# What's "ended in a disaster" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

I think it's 以灾难结局, and that people will understand that.  However, is there a more authentic term or is this it?

Comment: There are many ways. More context would help.

Comment: What actually do you wanna ask?
Do you wanna us to make sentenses with your phrase?

Comment: iciba翻译：在灾难中结束了，３ sample sentences using： 以悲剧收场、灾难性地破裂（了）、以彻底失败告终

Answer (score 1):

More native way is 災難收場.

～收場：

- 喜劇收場
- 悲劇收場
- 混亂收場

Another way is 大災難結局, for some big ending in drama and film.

大～結局 ：

- 大團圓結局

In writing, it could be 災難結尾.

～結尾：

- 歡喜結尾

You might use other words like 災難收尾, 災難而終.